# How to create tab in background for all major browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser

When a visit your site it will auto create a new tab in the background that redirects to another site while the current tab is still on focused. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: that script seems only to do onclick but I want it on visit

Comment: there are multiple solutions on that page and a lot of good discussion about what is and isn't possible regarding *opening a new tab with javascript*. the answers are going one step further and implementing that code as a click event, but the core question is the same.